# prove that the BM25 scoring function is probabilistic?

Tags: probability

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) says that this function is based on a probabilistic retrieval framework. However, how do you prove that the score *is* a probability. The ranking function is defined as follows:

> Given a query $Q$ containing keywords $q_1,...,q_n$ the score of the
>   document $D$ is given as above.
>
> $$score(D, Q)=\sum_{i=1}^n IDF(q_i) . \frac{f(q_i, D)\cdot(k_1+1)}{f(q_i, D)+k_1\cdot(1-b+b\cdot \frac{|D|}{avgdl})}$$
>
> where:
>
> - $f(q_i, D)$ is the frequency that keyword $q_i$ appears in document $D$.
> - $|D|$ is the length of the document (document size).
> - $avgdl$ is the average document length in the corpus (i.e. collection of documents).
> - $k_1$ & $b$ are free parameters
> - $IDF(q_i)$ is the inverse document frequency function. This is defined as follows: $$IDF(q_i)=\log\frac{N-n(q_i) +0.5}{n(q_i)+0.5}$$
>
> where:
>
> - $N$ is the total number of documents in the corpus
> - $n(q_i)$ is the number of documents which contain keyword $q_i$

There are various ways of computing IDF. However in an abstract sense, $$IDF=\frac{total\, no.of\,documents}{no.\,of\,documents\,which\,contain\,term\,q_i}$$

To me the inverse ($IDF^{-1}$) appears to give a probabilistic value. I can't predict anything about the second product in the equation either.

In tests I have observed that the score gives values $=> 0$ (not something between $0<score<1$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{no. of documents which contain term } q_i} {\text{total no. of documents}}$$ is the probability that a single document, sampled uniformly from the corpus, turns out to contain the term $q_i$.

$$\log\frac{n(q_i)+0.5}{N-n(q_i) +0.5}$$ is not a probability as it may be positive or negative (for example when $n(q_i) \gt \frac12N$) , and may be greater than or less than $1$ in magnitude.  But it may be close to the first within a restricted range of interest.

The score does not need to be a probability.  Its primary purpose is for ranking documents given particular queries, and in some circumstances it can be seen as a measure of relevant information.